# 'system' was not declared in this scope error

Tags: c, recursion, system, pause

So i dont get this error in other programs but i did get it in this.

This program is an example where i dont get the error.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {



    system("pause");
} // end main
```

but in this program below i get the error

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>

// Takes the number from function1, calculates the result and returns recursively.
int topla (int n) {
    if(n == 1)
    return 3;
    else
        return topla(n-1) + topla(n-1) + topla(n-1);
}

// Takes a number from main and calls function topla to find out what is 3 to the
// power of n 
int function1(int n) {
    return topla(n);
}

int main() {
    int n; // We us this to calculate 3 to the power of n

    printf("Enter a number n to find what 3 to the power n is: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    function1(n);

    system("pause");
} // end main
```

Comment: Why did you comment `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @iharob because i dont need it in other programs. but this one needs it for some reason.

Comment: `system()` is declared in `stdlib.h`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include `stdlib.h`, but don't use `system("pause")` as it's not standard and will not work on every system, just a simple `getchar()` (*or a loop involving `getchar()` since you've used `scanf()`*) should do the trick.

And normally `system("pause")` is found in windows command line programs because windows command prompt closes when the program exits, so maybe running the program from the command prompt directly would help, or using an IDE that fixes this like *geany*.

Finally always check the return value if `scanf()` instead of assuming that it worked.

Note: This code

```
return topla(n - 1) + topla(n - 1) + topla(n - 1)
```

you can write as

```
return 3 * topla(n - 1);
```

instead of calling `topla()` recursively 3 times.

And you don't really need the `else` because the function returns unless the `n != 1` so even without the `else` the recursion will stop when `n == 1`.

Comment: So is using system("pause"); like it is a standart part of a c program a mistake?

Comment: Yes it is. I only see it in windows console programs because of how windows IDE's work not because it's needed.

Comment: i didnt use certains things i could use in c because my friend asked me this question. and he said certain things like multiplying were not allowed in their exam. thats why i solved the question this way. But you are right about the else. I do this mistake a lot i will take note to not do that again.

Comment: It's not a mistake, it's just a style advice. Many programmers like the explicit `else`, multiplying was not allowed? that's a wierd restriction. Glad that it helped.

Comment: The n == 1 happens only one time. But n =! happens n-1 times. So would changing the places of the codes improve performance(i know this is a small program but i am asking this to learn). For example 

if (n =! 1) {
    return ...; }
return 3;

would this be better performancewise?

Comment: No I don't think it would in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The `system` function is declared in the standard header `<stdlib.h>`. If your program calls `system()`, you *must* have

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

at or near the top of your source file.

But part of your question is: why didn't the compiler complain when you omitted the `#include` directive?

The 1990 C standard (sometimes called "ANSI C") permits calls to functions that have not been explicitly declared.  If you write, for example:

```
system("pause");
```

with no visible declaration for the `system` function, it would be assumed that `system` is declared with a return type of `int` and parameters matching the arguments in the call -- in this case, a single argument of type `char*`. That happens to be consistent with the actual declaration of `system`, so with a C90 compiler, you can get away with omitting the `#include` directive. And some C compilers that support the more current 1999 and 2011 standards (which don't permit implicit declarations) still permit the old form, perhaps with a warning, for the sake of backward compatibility.

Even given a C90 compiler, there is no advantage to depending on the now obsolete "implicit `int`" rule.  Just add the `#include <stdlib.h>`.  More generally, for *any* library function you call, read its documentation and `#include` the header that declares it.

As for why you got an error with one of your programs and not another, I don't have an explanation for that. Perhaps you invoked your compiler with different settings. In any case, it doesn't really matter -- though you might look into how to configure your compiler so it *always* warns about things like this, so you can avoid this kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to know about two things.

Firstly, your code works absolutely fine and the program really finds the value of 3^n. So do not worry about that.

Coming to the system() part,

In order to use the `system();` function, you need to include the stdlib.h header file, as the function is declared in that header.

So it is a good practice to include the header (rather than commenting it).

Now, the pause keyword is used in windows, to stop the console from closing after the completion of the program and it is only for windows.

Note that, `system("pause");` is also not a standard, and it does not work on other machines, namely linux as, with the system command, you are directly interacting with the command line. In this regard, the commands for each operating system are specific, and they cannot be used for other OS.

so it is better that you use `getchar();` , a C standard library function, to hold the console window.

Comment: i didnt comment it. i didnt add it at all at first thinking i dont need it. i added it later to test. So using system pause is not a good thing. Its better to use something else when you can.

Comment: Yes. ` getchar(); ` is a good alternative. Also you can use a ` scanf(); ` .